# QGIS 3.22 - WFS will not load gives CRS Bounding Box error

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wfs

QGIS 3.22 does not appear to be compatible with my businesses WFS product but has been in the past.

When importing my WFS I receive two errors: "Used a ballpark transform from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:4283" and a pop up "Could not transform bounding box to target CRS".

This is not a GIS Server connection. It is a secured connection, but if anyone has any tips requiring access I can create a test login.

Get capabilities shows:

```
<FeatureType xmlns:cadnsw="cadnsw">
<Name>ProposedPlan</Name>
<Title>ProposedPlan</Title>
<DefaultCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4283</DefaultCRS>
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<ows:LowerCorner>-33.3687932517589 149.54769740538896</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>-33.36836572796 149.547992135073</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
</FeatureType>
<FeatureType xmlns:cadnsw="cadnsw">
<Name>ProposedParcel</Name>
<Title>ProposedParcel</Title>
<DefaultCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4283</DefaultCRS>
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<ows:LowerCorner>-33.3687932517589 149.54769740538896</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>-33.36836572796 149.547992135073</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
</FeatureType>
</FeatureTypeList>
```

8 GET https://cadastre.nsw.gov.au/wfs/?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&ACCEPTVERSIONS=2.0.0,1.1.0,1.0.0

Comment: Can you please add the url request qgis is sending? Also which version is being used

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for your response, i have added the request above. Please let me know if this is not what you were expecting. My technical knowledge is not advanced (if you couldn't tell!)

Comment: We need the request for the features

Comment: Need the GetFeature request, sent by QGIS not the GetCapabilities request

Comment: What is your businesses WFS product?

Comment: I am not sure how to find the GetFeatures request sent by QGIS. 

The WFS is a NSW LGA Proposed Property Layer for land subdivision (DPs/DAs etc) - it shows proposed plan geometry and relevant attributes (lot number/date of survey etc).

Comment: Use View > Panels > Debugging/Development tools  to get the requests sent by QGIS.  What software is being used to provide the WFS server?

Comment: Hi, I added the toolbar and its not giving me any requests at all. Only the CRS bounding box error. 

To see if there was another way to receive a log i tried one of our other products (WMS now) http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/services/public/NSW_Cadastre/MapServer/WMSServer 

its still giving me an error (adding this WMS doesn't require credentials). 

This product is inhouse but we use AWS services to host a lot of our products